# How can I load an object from another file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a JavaScript file `myscript.js` and I want to load an object from another file in it.

That other file looks like this:

```
{
  "A": {
    "B": {
      "C": "D",
      "E": "F"
    },
    "Q": {
      "C": "DD",
      "E": "CC"
    }
  },
  "BB": {
    "B": {
      "C": "FF",
      "E": "HH"
    },
    "Q": {
      "C": "AA",
      "E": "EE"
    }
  }
}
```

I get this generated out of a C# Service.

I could use it directly in my script like this:

```
var myobject = (the code above)
```

But I would like to load the code into `myobject` from another file, so I just have to replace the file with the object to update.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Fetch API](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)?

Comment: Tried, but failed :-p

Comment: Failed how? I suspect [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](/q/23667086/4642212) and [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](/q/14220321/4642212).